# Where did the standard controls for resource editor in VS2017 go?

Tags: visual-studio, resource-editor

I've upgraded from VS2008 to VS2017, all is well, but my first attempt to edit a resource has been problematic.   I need to add a button but I don't see how you do that with this version (and I don't want to have to edit the .rc file itself).  The `toolbox` tab as something called `MFC XXXX Control` but I'm not using MFC.  I'm looking for the normal controls like `Button`, `RichText`, `TreeView`, etc..   How do I get those to show up?  I don't see any option to do so.

TIA!!

Comment: Have you tried resetting the Toolbox? i.e. Right click within the Toolbox tab (somewhere in the background) and select `Reset Toolbox`.

Comment: that fixed it thanks, you should add a solution so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a feeling it was a matter of resetting the Toolbox. But for brevity sake if any other users experience this issue, if you ever need to reset the Toolbox back to the default set of user controls, you can do so by:

- Opening the Toolbox window (**View > Toolbox** or **Ctrl + W, X** if you're using C# shortcut settings)
- Right clicking anywhere in the Toolbox window
- In the context menu, select **Reset Toolbox**. This will reset all of your added/removed user controls back to the Visual Studio defaults

I will note that if you've added custom Toolbox items (via **Right click > Choose Items...** -- generally used for third party controls like DotNetBar), those items should still exist in the history, you would just have to re-enable them.

Glad to help!